# php trim won't work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, trim

So I have a server side ajax php file:

```
$thing = "\n\ncode\n";
echo(trim($thing, '\n'));
```

[image]

But when I use this php file for an ajax call, the responseText does not have newlines removed!

[image]

```
var xhr7 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr7.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr7.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr7.status == 200) {
      alert('trying');
      alert(xhr7.responseText);
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: xhr7.responseText });
    } else {
      alert("404 server side ajax file DOES NOT EXIST");
    }
  }
};
xhr7.open('POST', 'http://texthmu.com/Devin/HMU%20ext/Post-jsfile-forItsCode.php', true);
xhr7.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //following w3 
xhr7.send(); `
```

Comment: All escape characters are only interpreted by PHP when you enclose them in double quotes. Moreover you dont need to provide the second param if you just want to remove newlines, CRLFs, tabs or white space surrounding the word. Please refer to php.net/trim

Comment: ...And now with the actual JS code, newlines aren't cleared. 

trim( addslashes(file_get_contents("alert.js")), "\n" );

  -Ideas???

UPDATE: Got it: 
str_replace("\n", "", addslashes(file_get_contents($fileName)) )

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by, "And now with the JS code, newlines are picked up by"

Comment: I was was forgetting that trim only works on the beggining and end, great thanks to PhlipLip for pointing that out!

Comment: @devin, have you checked php.net/nl2br to convert all CRLFs to `<br>`?

Comment: @Kumar: The what? Have you understood what he's trying to do? Definately not nl2br!

Comment: @Phliplip, AFAIK, he wanted to trim `\n`s, second thing that I am not clear is may be there are more newlines in his text which he wants to remove or want those newlines to be converted to `<br>`s, if he simply wants to remove all `\n`s he can use `str_replace()` otherwise use `nlbr()` @Devin, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Kumar: He wishes to execute some JS that is fetched via AJAX, has nothing to do with HTML ;)

Comment: arghh!!! Thanks @Phliplip, I was thinking inside the box that @devin simply wants to replace some HTML using AJAX. D'oh!

Comment: @Kumar: There's more than meets the eye :-P

Answer (score 11):

\n needs to be in double quotes not single

```
echo(trim($thing, "\n"));
```

When a value is in single quotes, it's parsed as a literal. In this case `\n` instead of the new line character you're trying to trim.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the `\n` character in a double quoted (`"`) string.

PHP doesn't interpet these special characters in single quote (`'`) delimited strings.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
$thing = "\n\ncode\n"; 
echo(trim($thing));
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:
>
> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

**Additional for the comments below**

Please note that;

```
$thing = "\n\nco\nde\n"; // See the \n between co and de ? 
echo(trim($thing, "\n"));
```

If you wish that it be removed too, then trim is not the right function for you.

If you wish to remove ALL \n from a string, then you should use

```
str_replace("\n", "", $thing);
```

Comment: What if he wants to keep spaces, tabs, carriage return, null and vertical-tab?

Comment: yeah I am actually trimming newlines out of javascript code, so spaces are needed.

Comment: Please note that trim will only strip spaces (and newlines) from the beginning and end of your string. Looking at your JS, why do you need spaces (and tabs, CR, vertical tab, NUL-bytes) kept in the beginning and end of your string?